# edit xml layout joomla

Tags: xml, layout, joomla

I have istalled a joomla template recently and I can see that it uses xml structure for the layout. Im not very familiar with this. I can work with existing tags but I want to add something and I cant find the appropriate tag

this is the structure for the header:

```
<header1 order="1" id="yt_top" autosize="0">
<positions>
    <position width="" height="" type="modules">top2</position>
</positions>
</header1>              
<header2 order="2" id="yt_header" autosize="0">
<positions>
    <position width="" height="" type="feature">@logo</position>
    <position width="" height="" type="modules">logo_text</position>
    <position width="" height="" type="modules">header2</position>
</positions>
</header2>
<menu order="3" id="yt_menuwrap" autosize="0">
<positions>
       <position width="" type="feature">@menu</position>
</positions>
</menu>
```

As you can see it divides the header into 3 parts but i need to have the header inside one outer "div" (if i was using html) and then these 3 as childs of it.

Ive tried adding a general tag like

```
<header></header>
<content></content>
<group></group>
<block></block>
```

nothing works, any suggestions?

Comment: Is this by any chance a Yootheme template? If so, which file does this code belong to?

Comment: is is actually a smartaddons theme but I have seen this structure on other templates too, maybe jootheme too. the file is located on template folder/layout/main-right.xml

Comment: Maybe you would be best off contacting the developer of the template

Comment: yes probably that will give me a solution right now. I was just wondering whether there are specific tags like html tags for these kind of xml files or each template has its own structure and then again where do you define them

Answer (score 0):

Many template companies extend the Joomla framework with their personal approach to making layout as flexible as possible to use, introducing an extra layer to process the layout options; you'd be better off contacting them or debugging their code.

The joomla way is to simply define position names in the template manifest (xml file), and then load those positions in the template's `index.php`:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="search" />
```

much easier to read, although possibly not as configurable.